# Retrieve data from nsdictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

Here's my JSON file :

```
 {"object":

     {"blog":[{"guid":181,"type":"object","subtype":"4","time_created":"1376731708","time_updated":"1376731708","container_guid":"180","owner_guid":"180","site_guid":"1","title":"ugg sito ufficiale italiavyt","description":"sdataa","url":"http:\urlt"}],

    "bookmarks":[
        {"guid":82,"type":"object","subtype":"9","time_created":"1372072736","time_updated":"1372072910","container_guid":"81","owner_guid":"33","site_guid":"1","title":"Eqtitler","description":"<description>","url":"http:\urler"},
        {"guid":75,"type":"object","subtype":"9","time_created":"1371728924","time_updated":"1371728924","container_guid":"64","owner_guid":"52","site_guid":"1","title":"Ttitleur","description":"<pdescriptionp>","url":"http:\urlr"}
    ]
},

"group":[
    [
        {"guid":83,"type":"group","subtype":"0","time_created":"1372073952","time_updated":"1372074727","container_guid":"33","owner_guid":"33","site_guid":"1","name":"titles","description":"description>","url":"http:\urls"},
        {"guid":81,"type":"group","subtype":"0","time_created":"1372067304","time_updated":"1372068113","container_guid":"33","owner_guid":"33","site_guid":"1","name":"titles","description":"<pdescriptionp>","url":"http:\/\urles"},
        {"guid":64,"type":"group","subtype":"0","time_created":"1371728148","time_updated":"1372068044","container_guid":"33","owner_guid":"33","site_guid":"1","name":"Gtitres","description":"<description>","url":"http:\/\urls"}
    ]
]
  }
```

I use the following code to parse my json:

```
 NSError *error = nil;
 NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://s210678217.onlinehome.fr/?view=json"]];

 id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

 NSDictionary *feed = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"object"];
 NSArray *entries = [feed objectForKey:@"bookmarks"];
```

Or

```
NSArray *entries2 = [feed objectForKey:@"blog"];
```

This code works perfectly to retrieve data with bookmarks and blog.
Only, this code can not retrieve group.
I do not understand why?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `{` in json before `group`. correct it then
Try this:

```
NSArray *entries = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"group"];
```

group is array of `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use json-framework to parse any json string.   You should import "SBJSON.h" in your class and the following code parses your JSON to a NSArray.

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourURL"]];
NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest returningResponse: &resp error: &error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //your json string from URL request
//JSON Parsing here
SBJsonParser* parser = [SBJsonParser new];
NSArray* myArr = [parser objectWithString:jsonString];    //parsed NSArray
```

You can download this framework here:(https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) 
You should have a valid JSON however to parse it.